# How can I assign a rank to column values, and only show the highest ranked value for each line item in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, serialization, ranking

I'll try my best to explain what I need. I have a query that is left joining multiple tables. I cannot post the actual query so I will give an example.

The left table (Table A) contains 50 unique serial numbers. The query output must always return only one row per unique serial number. One of the tables (Table B) I am joining to (on the serial number value) has multiple values in one of the columns I am selecting. The Column is status, and the values are Installed, DOA, or Missing. A serial number can have more than one value in the status column which is results in multiple rows for one serial.

So if serial number 1234 has an Installed record and a DOA record, I get two rows back for that serial instead of one, meaning the output of the query gives me 51 rows with one duplicate serial number instead of 50 rows.

I want to assign ranks to the status column values, for example Installed=1, DOA=2, and Missing=3. I want the query to only show the highest ranked value, or NULL no if no value is present.

If a Serial has an installed record and a DOA record, it shows Installed in the output, if it has a DOA but no Installed, then it Shows DOA.

What I get:

```
TABLE A SN  TABLE B SN  TABLE B STATUS
1234        1234        Installed
1234        1234        DOA
5678        5678        DOA
```

What I want:

```
TABLE A SN  TABLE B SN  TABLE B STATUS
1234        1234        Installed
5678        5678        DOA
```

Is this possible to do it SQL, if not are there other functions I can use to achieve the a similar result?

Comment: Are there ever instances when there are two records with the same installed status and SN, and if so do you want it to choose one or return both?  The answers below will work if you want only ever one row per SN.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using `row_number()` with conditional ordering:

```
with cte as (
    select a.sn asn, b.sn bsn, b.status,
        row_number() over (partition by a.sn 
            order by 
                case when b.status = 'Installed' then 1
                    when b.status = 'DOA' then 2
                    when b.status = 'Missing' then 3
                end) rn
    from tablea a 
       left join tableb b on a.sn = b.sn
)
select asn, bsn, status
from cte
where rn = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02e0e/2)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do what you want.  Here is one method using `outer apply` and `choose()`:

```
select a.sn. b.*
from tablea a outer apply
     (select top 1 b.*
      from tableb b
      where b.sn = a.sn
      order by choose(b.status, 'Installed', 'DOA', 'Missing')
     ) b;
```

Note:  by "highest rank" I'm not sure what the ordering is.  You might want a `desc` on the `order by`.